# correct syntax using rxjs observables, helper functions, and promises

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I am unable to correctly write a code.

So far I am:

```
  getTender(id: number): Observable<TenderResponse> {

    const tender$ = this.get<TenderResponse>('/tenders/' + id);
    const images$ = tender$.pipe(mergeMap((tender: TenderResponse): Observable<TenderResponse> => {
        return combineLatest(
          tender.locations.loading.map(
            (location: TenderLocation, index: number) => {
              location.not_uploaded_images = from(this.fileService.getCargoImagesAtLocation(location.id));

              return location;
            }
          )
        )
      }
    );

    return images$;
  }
```

The idea, that the method should get an Object(Tender).
When it is loaded - it has a list of locations, each location has an id.
Using these ids (for reach location) - I should get a list of images.
And then return the result - The tender with location with images.

Currently this code is not working, because of incompatible types and deprecations

**this.fileService.getCargoImagesAtLocation** is a promise, so I use rxjs `from` operator to convert it to observable..

The result of the **getTender** method should be of type **Observable**.

**UPDATED CODE:**

```
  getImages(locationId: number): Observable<NotUploadedImage[]> {
    return from(this.fileService.getCargoImagesAtLocation(locationId));
  }

  getTender(id: number): Observable<TenderResponse> {
    return this.get<TenderResponse>('/tenders/' + id).pipe(
      mergeMap(
        (tender: TenderResponse): Observable<TenderResponse> => {
          tender.locations.loading.forEach((location: TenderLocation) => {
            location.not_uploaded_images = this.getImages(location.id);
          });
          return of(tender);
        }
      )
    );
  }
```

The problem is that the not_uploaded_images does not get resolved, and the property of returned Tender object is a type of `Observable`, but it must be a type of `NotUploadedImages[]`.

I think it is because the operator `combineLatest` is not used. But once I use it - I can't setup the code correctly.

**FINAL WORKING RESULT:**

```
  getImages(locationId: number): Observable<NotUploadedImage[]> {
    return from(this.fileService.getCargoImagesAtLocation(locationId));
  }

  getTender(id: number): Observable<TenderResponse> {
    return this.get<TenderResponse>('/tenders/' + id).pipe(
      mergeMap((tender: TenderResponse) =>
        combineLatest(
          tender.locations.loading.map((location: TenderLocation) =>
            this.getImages(location.id)
          )
        ).pipe(
          map((images: NotUploadedImage[][]) => {
            return tender.locations.loading.map(
              (location: TenderLocation, index: number): TenderLocation => {
                return {
                  ...location,
                  not_uploaded_images: images[index],
                };
              }
            );
          }),
          map((locations: TenderLocation[]) => {
            tender.locations.loading = locations;
            return tender;
          })
        )
      )
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, but `location.not_uploaded_images = from...` and `return location;` don't add up. You're not returning the Observable.

Perhaps this is what you want (and a little more concise):

```js
return combineLatest(
    tender.locations.loading.map((location: TenderLocation) => 
        from(this.fileService.getCargoImagesAtLocation(location.id))
    )
)
```

#### Edit

To answer your comments. If I understand correctly, the `mergeMap` takes your parent Object as an input and subscribes to a new Observable. That new Observable has two purposes: get the images; return them along with the parent Object. To do this, we can create a second pipe and map within the context of the mergeMap function.

Based on your stackblitz link, this should work:

```js
getTender(id: number): Observable<TenderResponse> {
    return this.serviceThatGetsTender(id)
        .pipe(
            mergeMap((tender: TenderResponse) =>
                combineLatest(
                  tender.locations.loading.map((location: TenderLocation) => this.getImages(location.id))
                )
                .pipe(
                  map(images => tender.locations.loading.map(
                    (t, i) => ({ ...t, not_uploaded_images: images[i] } as TenderLocation)
                  )),
                  map(locations => {
                    tender.locations.loading = locations;
                    return tender
                  })
                )
            )
        )
}
```

Note the returned object: `Observable<{tender: TenderResponse, images: NotUploadedImage}>`. This is just because I don't know all the fields in your objects, I assume you want to place the images onto the TenderResponse Object.

Also, regarding your warning: make sure you are importing the correct `combineLatest`. There is one under `'rxjs'` and one under `'rxjs/operators'`. You require the former.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But there are still incompatible type errors. `Type 'Observable<NotUploadedImage[][]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<TenderResponse>'.
  Type 'NotUploadedImage[][]' is missing the following properties from type 'TenderResponse': id, number, locations, cargo, and 2 more.ts(2322)`

Comment: (tender: TenderResponse): Observable<TenderResponse> => {
          return combineLatest(

Comment: You've declared your function as returning `Observable<TenderResponse>` but your code returns `Observable<NotUploadedImage[][]>`. Either adjust your `mergeMap` /  `combineLatest` to return what you want, or adjust your function definition to match what is actually being returned.

Comment: I understand the error, but I do not understand how to syntactically correct write the thing that I need.

I want to return `Observable<TenderResponse>` as it is in original, but the property in the tender.locations.loading[].not_uploaded_image should be filled for each location, before returning the tender. It means that there must be made several async operations after the first one (get the tender itself) which will modify tender, by filling the property and then tender itself (with filled properties) must be returned.

Comment: plus I see this warning: `@deprecated — resultSelector no longer supported, pipe to map instead`

Comment: Thanks I just did something similar. Can you check the updated code, please? There is an issue that the Observable does not get resolved before the return.

Comment: I don't mean to sound petulant, but read the first line of my answer. And read the updated part carefully as well. What you're doing is _not_ similar, at all.

Comment: check line 102 - and you will see the root of the problem, may be you can fix it online, so I can see the solution? Thank you!

Comment: See re-edited edit, above. I wasn't sure how to save the stackblitz...

Comment: Here: the fork option was just bugged out for me... https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-vtkr7z?file=index.ts

Comment: Can I ask, is this for a logistics app of some sort?

Comment: Is it established? Have you a website? I have a logistics app as well, but it's been parked, thinking about relaunching it.

Comment: Yes, you can checkout www.cagotenders.com.

Comment: Btw, I have checked your code - it works, but, should we reply on the indexes, when mapping locations to the tender.locations? Or it is better to mark images, having them locationId, so we can map images to locations using locationId? Or it can be left as is - and there will be no error cases here?

Comment: I meant, when mapping `images` to `location.not_uploaded_images`.

Comment: So long as `getImages` always returns an array, even if it's empty, then this code will be safe.